# Docker in docker and docker compose block one port for no reason

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

Right now I am setting up an application that has a deployment based upon docker images.

I use gitlab ci to:

1. Test each service
2. Build each service
3. Dockerize each image (create docker container)
4. Run integration tests (start docker compose that starts all services on special ports, run integration tests)
5. Stop prod images and run new images

I did this for each service, but I ran into an issue.

When I start my docker container for integration tests then it is setup within a gitlab ci task. For each task a docker based runner is used. I also mount my host docker socket to be able to use docker in docker.

So my gradle docker image is started by the gitlab runner. Then docker will be installed and all images will be started using docker compose.

One microservice listens to port 10004. Within the docker compose file there is a 11004:10004 port mapping.

My integration tests try to connect to port 11004. But this does not work right now.

When I attach to the image that run docker compose while it tries to execute the integration test then I am not able to do it manually by calling

```
wget ip: port
```

I just get the message connected and waiting for response. Either my tests can connect successfully. My service does not log any message about a new connection.

When I execute this `wget` command within  my host shell then it works.

It's a public ip and within my container I can also connect to other ports using `telnet` and `wget`. Just one port of one service is broken when I try to connect from my docker in docker instance.

When I do not use docker compose then it works. Docker compose seems to setup a special default network that does something weird.

Setting network to host also works...

So did anyone also make such an experience when using docker compose?

The same setup works flawless in docker for mac, but my server runs on Debian 8.

My solution for now is to use a shell runner to avoid docker in docker issues. It works there as well.

So docker in docker combined with docker compose seems to have an ugly bug.

I'm writing while I am sitting in the subway but I hope describing my issue is also sufficient to talk about experiences. I don't think we need some sourcecode to find bad configurations because it works without docker in docker and on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that docker in docker has still some weird behaviors. I fixed my issue by adding a new gitlab ci runner that is a shell runner. Therefore docker-compose is run on my host and everything works flawless.

I can reuse the same runner for starting docker images in production as I do for integration testing. So the easy fix has another benefit for me.

The result is a best practice to avoid pitfalls:

Only use docker in docker when there is a real need.

For example to make sure fast io communication between your host docker image and your docker image of interest.

Have fun using docker (in docker (in docker))  :]